# If there are two electrical conductors in a circuit with differing electrical conductivities will electricity choose the most conductive conductor?

Tags: copper, conductivity, conductors

Say you had two parallel wires, one copper and one steel, copper having a much higher conductivity than the steel, will electricity choose to flow through the copper wire, ignoring the steel wire?

Comment: A song to remind you: I'll take the high road, you take the low road...

Comment: if there is voltage applied across the steel wire, then what would prevent current flow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current flows *proportionally* through *all* paths. It doesn't "choose" anything. Some posts you might find helpful to clarify that:

- [Electricity takes the path of least resistance?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5670/1638) on Physics Stack Exchange
- [Path of least resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_of_least_resistance) on Wikipedia

  Excerpt:

  > In electrical circuits, for example, the current always follows all available paths, and in some simple cases the "path of least resistance" will take up most of the current, but this will not be generally true in even slightly more complicated circuits.

Let's run the math:

First, we need to know the resistivity \$\rho\$ (or its reciprocal, conductivity \$\sigma\$) of the materials. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Resistivity_and_conductivity_of_various_materials):

- **Copper** resistivity at 20 °C is \$1.68 \times 10^{-8} \, \Omega \cdot \text{m}\$.
- **Carbon steel (1010)** resistivity at 20 °C is \$14.3 \times 10^{-8} \, \Omega \cdot \text{m}\$.

To convert this to resistance, we also need a length and cross-sectional area of the wire. I will use one meter with a 2 mm diameter (1 mm radius), roughly 12 AWG.

Cross-sectional area is found using:

$$A=\pi r^2$$

The cross-sectional area of our wire then is \$3.14 \text{mm}^2\$ (or \$3.14\times 10^{-6} \text{m}^2\$).

The conversion formula is:

$$R = \frac{\rho L}{A}$$

Where \$\rho\$ is resistivity, \$L\$ is length, and \$A\$ is cross-sectional area.

Calculated wire resistance is then:

- 1 meter of 2 mm dia. copper wire: \$R = \frac{(1.68\times 10^{-8} \Omega \cdot \text{m}) (1 \text{m})}{3.14 \times 10^{-6} \text{m}^2} = 0.005 \Omega\$
- 1 meter of 2 mm dia. carbon steel wire: \$R = \frac{(14.3 \times 10^{-8} \Omega \cdot \text{m}) (1 \text{m})}{3.14 \times 10^{-6} \text{m}^2} = 0.046 \Omega\$

If we apply 1 volt:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEl7Ex.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We can calculate current through each using Ohm's Law \$I = \frac{E}{R}\$:

- Current through **copper** = \$\frac{1}{0.005} = 200 \text{A}\$
- Current through **steel** = \$\frac{1}{0.046} = 21.7 \text{A}\$

**Conclusion:** Both wires conduct, but copper conducts about 9 times better then carbon steel, so there's 9 times more current.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, **more goes down the better, copper, conductor and less goes down the worse, steel, conductor.**  (Assuming they're they same diameter and length.)

How much goes which way is a straightforward parallel resistor question.  You work out the resistances of same shaped wires (I chose 1 km of 1 mm<sup>2</sup> cross section just for illustration) by looking up resistivities from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity), and then you apply Ohm's law to find out how much goes each way.

You will see V=IR shows how much goes each way:

V = I<sub>copper</sub> * R<sub>copper</sub> = I<sub>steel</sub> * R<sub>steel</sub>.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXiH25.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

It will "choose" copper more than steel, because copper is more conductive than steel.

But it won't *ignore* the steel wire.  If you added more different parallel wires, including "wires" that were not even wires at all (such as nylon, hair, twine etc.) the important thing to understand is that current will flow down all of these also - just much less of it, due to them being such poor conductors.

Answer (score 2):

Of course... The two conductors can be considered as two "resistors" in parallel that form a [current divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider). The current will split into two parts whose magnitude is inversely proportional to the resistances.

Answer (score 0):

Say you had two parallel roads, one 3-lane and one 1-lane. Will traffic choose to flow through the 3-lane road, ignoring the 1-lane road?

Of course not. Experience tells us that traffic will balance out so that each lane carries the same level of traffic.

In the case of your wires you could split the copper strands out into bunches of wires with the same resistance as the steel wire. Now each of those bunches will carry the same current as the steel wire.

Answer (score 0):

Steel has more resistance than copper, but cross-sectional area of conductor is a factor also.

$$R = \frac {\rho \ell} {A}$$.

where \$\rho\$ is resistivity of material (at a specific temperature), \$\ell\$ is length of conductor and \$A\$ is cross-sectional area of conductor.

\$\rho_{Cu} = 1.68×10^{−8} \Omega \cdot m\$ and \$\rho_{Carbon\ Steel} = 14.3×10^{−8} \Omega \cdot m\$.  Which makes Copper 8.5 times more conductive than Carbon Steel.

But we have not taken the area into account.  Resistance is inversely propotional to area squared.  So 1mm of copper wire would be equivalent to 2.92mm of carbon steel wire.

If the wires have the same cross-sectional area, copper will conduct a greater percentage than steel, but if the steel wire is 2.92 times the copper diameter, it will have the same resistance and conduct just as much as the copper conductor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXsT0X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Schematic from jonathanjo's answer.**

Comment: I'm surprised at the near-identical schematic to jonathanjo.

Comment: I plagerized his schematic!